# How to solve this modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am not able to solve this Equation :

$$x^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{10^9+7}$$

**$x$ is a positive integer.**

What is the general approach to do this ?

Comment: Do you have to solve it, or do you need that a solution exists? Because showing existence is easier. You can use quadratic reciprocity, recalling that $10^9+7$ is prime.

Comment: In response to your first sentence:  Neither is anyone else.  (Because $10^9 + 7 \not \cong 1,4 \pmod 5)$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a legendre symbol. 10^9+7 is a prime number then for $x^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{10^9+7}$ solution exist $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\left(\dfrac5{10^9+7} \right)=1$. $\left(\dfrac5{10^9+7} \right)=(-1)^{\frac{5-1}2\frac{10^9+7-1}2}\left(\dfrac{10^9+7}5 \right)=\left(\dfrac{10^9+7}5 \right)=\left(\dfrac25 \right)=(-1)^{\frac{5^2-1}8}=-1$ therefore solution doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) is useful.